# How to draw a line before a text in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a text **About us** on a webpage in which I want to [draw a blue line](https://postimg.org/image/aihivxab3/) 
before it. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r469bcx4/5/embedded/result/) for the webpage. I am wondering how can I use the selectors to achieve that in CSS ? or any other way in CSS in order to achieve that ?

The HTML code for the **About us** section which I am using is:

```
<div class="about-homesail">
  <p class="headline-text">About Us</p>
  <p class="company-info">aha hahahah ahahahhaha hahhahhahh hahahhh hhhahah hha hahhha hahhhah ahhhhahah ahhhhhhahq...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That image of a blue line doesn't help to describe your situation. "Before" could mean a lot of things...

Comment: vertical line before or horizontal line above?

Comment: look at `::before` or `border-top`

Comment: @sheriffderek I have edited the fiddle and image link. Hope that helps.

Comment: @user5447339 - that is much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `:before` to create a pseudo-element that houses the border, which would not affect the text. Something like this:

```
.about-homesail .headline-text:before {
  border-top: 1px solid #1072B8;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -25px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  content: "";
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3fruwccb/

Answer (score 0):

You use the before selector to insert a line before the About us and set color:blue;

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use `::before` selector.
It creates a pseudo-element that is the first child of the selected element. It is often used to add cosmetic content to an element with the content property.

You can use the following code:

```
   .headline-text::before {
         content: "";
         position: absolute;
         width: 100%;
         border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
      }
```

[Learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::before)

Answer (score 0):

Here are all of the ways: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/feqfj54o/

```
<hr />

<h2 class='special-heading'>I'm a level 2 heading</h2>

<section class='section-name'>
  <h2>Some text...</h2>

  <p>Some stuff in a section</p>
</section>


<section class='with-before-element'>
  <h2>Section using a 'before' or 'after' psuedo element</h2>
</section>
```

...

```
hr {
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background: red;
}


.special-heading {
  border-top: 1px solid blue;
}

.section-name {
  border-top: 1px solid green;
}


.with-before-element {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.with-before-element:before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  /* these 'psuedo' elements need a content declaration even if you don't have any.... */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: orange;
}
```